# Using Jquery UI Slider to trigger Resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-resizable

Has anyone used the slider to trigger resizable? This way, we can use the values from the slider to manipulate the width and height of another element. Here is a an example:

```
$("#myslider").slider({
        value: 50,
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $( ".scalablediv" ).resizable({
               resize: function(event, ui) {
               ui.size.width = ui.value;
            }
     });        
   }
});

<div class="scalablediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the trigger on `slide` event of the slider, and inside you can set the width and height of the `scalablediv`. Making `scalablediv` to `resizable` doesn't actually resize it but instead making it to a `resizable` object, which is different. Here's the fiddle for the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6KSbp/1/. Thanks